# Does coffee consumption cause continuous chest pain?

Tags: caffeine, health

I drink coffee twice a day for almost a month. Lately, for last few week, I feel chest pain right after drinking coffee. I initially thought that was some gastric related problem. But even after continuing my gastric med for over a week I'm still feeling the pain. And I  must say it doesn't feel like a typical acidity-caused chest pain. Is it caused by coffee, should I stop drinking it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for medical advice.

Answer (score 9):

Similar questions have been answered in [Coffee SE](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) several times. So please check these previous questions first. I'm enlisting the most related ones I can think of below:

- [How many cups of coffee is it safe to consume per day?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-many-cups-of-coffee-is-it-safe-to-consume-per-day)
- [What are the side effects of drinking too much coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/464/what-are-the-side-effects-of-drinking-too-much-coffee)
- [Can drinking coffee at least once a day increase anxiety?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2519/can-drinking-coffee-at-least-once-a-day-increase-anxiety)
- [Coffee on daily basis](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/coffee-on-daily-basis)

Based on these, one can say, regular coffee consumption shouldn't be a problem for a regular healthy person.

Specifically for your question, my humble advice is that you should see a physician. People who are into coffee cannot diagnose others based on coffee consumption habits.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any underlying health issues you may try eating a small cookie or biscuit with your coffee.  It seems to help me.  I think that is why they serve them with coffee in sidewalk cafes (never been but I watch old movies).

Answer (score 1):

I used to have chest pain and I discovered after going to the doctor that it was actually costochondritis, which is an inflammation of cartilage that was tying my ribs to my muscles. The pain would seem to rotate from place to place.Mayo Clinic has a great page on it here: [Costochondritis](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/costochondritis/basics/definition/con-20024454)

I have a tremendous love of coffee myself and if my doctor said "give it up or you're dead", I would promptly reply "I have made peace with my deity". ;-)