# What should be the daily coffee intake?

Tags: health, caffeine

I am from Pakistan. Summers here are very hot. My question is how many cups of coffee are recommended as a daily intake in summers? should the daily intake of coffee vary in summers and winters?

Comment: As long as you drink plenty of water it will not make a difference. (I'm not a doctor.) I've lived in very hot places and very cold places and currently live in NYC which has a good range of temperatures. I have not noticed any reason to moderate my consumption due to the temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This, or similar questions have been answered a few times. Each time, they are phrased a bit differently with new perspectives, so I would like to answer these, also add the previous discussions.*

Starting in the reverse order, drinking coffee in alternating seasons should not matter. Actually, this boils down how much water your metabolism consume in summer or in winter time. As well as, how much water you consumed: plain or in coffee form -which is more common. In Coffee SE, we have discussed caffeine related dehydration a few times, where the following two discussions has extended answers:

- [Does coffee cause dehydration?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/149/does-coffee-cause-dehydration)
- [Will I get dehydrated from drinking coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/will-i-get-dehydrated-from-drinking-coffee)

Then, as the second part of your question whether there exists a limit for coffee consumption? Yes, there is. Actually, the limit for caffeine intake is so high that under normal conditions even the water you consumed together with your coffee become deadly at that point. Still, if you want to see the answer it is here:

- [What is the limit to the amount of coffee one can consume?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/what-is-the-limit-to-the-amount-of-coffee-one-can-consume/2858#2858)

And, finally, you may wonder whether is there a suggested amount. Yes, there is:

- [How many cups of coffee is it safe to consume per day?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/221/how-many-cups-of-coffee-is-it-safe-to-consume-per-day)